# Scalling Feature implemented in DataFrame modelling

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

I have dataset with 15 columns  with below scenario
9 -columns are categorical use so I have convert the data  one hot encoder

6 columns are numeric, out of 6 - 3 columns is having outlier since column values are different range, so I have chosen RobustScaler() as scaling features and other I chosen standard Scalar.
after that I have combined all the data frame and apply the Logistic Regression algorithm my model produced very low score even I got the good score with out scaling.

will any one can able to help on this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

please apply column standardization to data frame and see the output..I guess since logistic regression is sensitive to outliers,you are facing problem

impute outliers properly and then apply column standardization